# Incluir SSL en la petición OkHttp3

Tags: android, ssl, https, certificado-ssl

Tengo una aplicación web que ya esta sobre *HTTPS* y tiene un certificado *SSL* pago. Cuando navego hacia esta pagina, me muestra que la conexión es segura. Ya quedó configurada bien con el certificado.

Suponiendo que la pagina es `https://example.gov.co/`, en la aplicación móvil se conecta a la API con esta ruta `https://example.gov.co:443`. ¿Tengo que hacer algo adicional en la app móvil para que use ese certificado *SSL*?

Este es el código de conexión.

```
final HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new HeaderInterceptor())
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constantes.API_REST_URL_BASE)
            .client(client)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create());

    builder.addConverterFactory(createGsonConverter());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://square.github.io/okhttp/https/):

> Al negociar una conexión a un servidor `HTTPS`, `OkHttp` necesita saber
>   qué versiones de TLS y conjuntos de cifrado ofrecer. Un cliente que
>   quiera maximizar la conectividad incluiría versiones TLS obsoletas y
>   conjuntos de cifrado de diseño débil. Un cliente estricto que quiera
>   maximizar la seguridad se limitaría solo a la última versión de TLS y
>   a los conjuntos de cifrado más potentes.
>
> ConnectionSpec implementa las decisiones específicas de seguridad
>   frente a conectividad. OkHttp incluye cuatro especificaciones de
>   conexión incorporadas:
>
> `RESTRICTED_TLS` es una configuración segura, destinada a cumplir
>   requisitos de cumplimiento más estrictos. `MODERN_TLS` es una
>   configuración segura que se conecta a los servidores HTTPS modernos.
>   `COMPATIBLE_TLS` es una configuración segura que se conecta a
>   servidores `HTTPS` seguros, pero no actuales. `CLEARTEXT` es una
>   configuración insegura que se usa para http: // URLs. Estos siguen
>   libremente el modelo establecido en las Políticas de Google Cloud.
>   Hacemos un seguimiento de los cambios a esta política.
>
> Por defecto, `OkHttp` intentará una conexión `MODERN_TLS`. Sin embargo, al
>   configurar las especificaciones de conexión del cliente, puede
>   permitir un retroceso a la conexión `COMPATIBLE_TLS` si falla la
>   configuración moderna.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS, ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS))
        .build();
```

Por lo tanto define en tu cliente lo siguiente:

```
final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new HeaderInterceptor())
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS, ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS))
            .build();
```

Para más información relacionada a que certificados puedes configurar para que sean permitidos puedes revisar la [documentación OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/https/)